# System.EngineExecutionException in unsuspected place

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I am trying to fill LongListSelector with values from webservice.
After I get Contractors I get System.EngineExecutionException when I'm trying making new List I dunno how should I avoid it.

Anyone can help me handle it?

```
  private async void fillLongList()
    {

        Contractors contr = await pobierzSieciHandlowe();
        listaSieci = new List<SieciHandloweList>();
        foreach (Contractor c in contr.contractors)
        {
            listaSieci.Add(new SieciHandloweList(c.name, "test", c.logos.logo_60_url));
        }
        List<SieciHandloweGroup<SieciHandloweList>> DataSource = SieciHandloweGroup<SieciHandloweList>.CreateGroups(listaSieci,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, (SieciHandloweList s) => { return s.NazwaSklepu; }, true);
        llsSieciHandlowe.ItemsSource = DataSource;
    }
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the exception?

Comment: listaSieci = new List<SieciHandloweList>();